# Implementation of Deref for container structure

Tags: rust

I have the next code, that implements some kind of lazy/deferred init and I want to use interior mutability and Deref implementation for convenience.

```
pub struct Deferred<T> {
    value: RefCell<Value<T>>
}

pub enum Value<T> {
    Initialized(T),
    WaitingForValue
}

impl<T> Deferred<T> {
    pub fn init_later() -> Self {
        Self { value: RefCell::new(WaitingForValue) }
    }
    pub fn init(&self, value: T) {
        self.value.replace(Initialized(value));
    }
}

impl<T> Deref for Deferred<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        if let Initialized(value) = self.value.borrow().deref() {
            value
        } else {
            panic!("Deferred value must be initialized before the first usage")
        }
    }
}
```

But I've got an error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
   |
30 |         if let Initialized(value) = self.value.borrow().deref() {
   |                                     ------------------- temporary value created here
31 |             value
   |             ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I've tried different reference types, but can't get it working.

Also, I've tried to do that with unsafe:

```
fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
    unsafe {
        if let Initialized(value) = &*self.value.as_ptr() {
            &value
        } else {
            panic!("Deferred value must be initialized before the first usage")
        }
    }
}
```

It works in this case, but I'm not sure that this unsafe code doesn't produce undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You cant return a shared reference from a `RefCell` because the borrow checking is made at runtime via the `Ref` and `RefMut`, thoses wrapper implement `as_ref<Inner>` but the produced references is owned by the wrapper (`Ref`/`RefMut`) so you must keep it on the scoop.

This make the traits `deref` and `as_ref` not easy to use but you can get the same behaviour by implementing `Deref` on `Value<T>` instead of `Deffered`, for instance

```
use std::{cell::{RefCell}, ops::{Deref}};

pub struct Deferred<T> {
    value: RefCell<Value<T>>
}

pub enum Value<T> {
    Initialized(T),
    WaitingForValue
}

impl<T> Deferred<T> {
    pub fn init_later() -> Self {
        Self { value: RefCell::new(Value::WaitingForValue) }
    }
    pub fn init(&self, value: T) {
        self.value.replace(Value::Initialized(value));
    }
}

/// Implement deref on `Value` instead of `Deferred`
impl<T> Deref for Value<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        if let Value::Initialized(value) = self {
            value
        } else {
            panic!("Deferred value must be initialized before a first usage")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = Deferred::init_later();
    val.init(String::from("Hello, world !"));
    let _: &String = val.value.borrow().deref();
}
```